# How to concatenate column name for Select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Now before you go crazy with this question and begin critizicing this way of thinking, let me tell you I agree with you, this completely unnormalized database design disgusts me as much as the next person, we however, have to work with it so let's get to it.

There is a database, with 12 columns, one for each month of the year (I know, I know..), actually 24 columns when you count the ones that state what gets in and what gets out.

They are labeled Month1, Month2, etc. As you'd expect..

I'm trying to find a way to systematically choose a column based on a, wait for it, yes! Month value, so 1 for January, etc..

So far this hasn't worked:

```
SELECT Month+1 ...
```

Or this:

```
SELECT Month+@myMonth
```

So while my first option would've been to build a good database, I don't have the means and even if I did I wouldn't be allowed to.

So is there a way to sort this out? Without the need to create a 24 cases long Select Case?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetByMonth
(
    @month int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT CASE @month
        WHEN 1 THEN Month1
        WHEN 2 THEN Month2
        --...
    END AS MonthData
    FROM Table1
)
```

That you can then select from later without having to always write out the CASE:

```
SELECT MonthData
FROM GetByMonth(2) AS m
```

Or,

```
SELECT a.Month, m.MonthData
FROM Table2 a
CROSS APPLY GetByMonth(a.Month) m
```

Comment: You make sense, and I'm affraid I'll have to go with something like this in the end. I think something as simple as this should be implemented in SQL Server. Although I'm sure there are very valid reasons for it not be.

Comment: You could also use dynamic SQL, but if this does the job, I recommend going this way and only using dynamic SQL as a last resort.

Comment: Is there a problem with using dynamic SQL? Not saying I'm going to, I'm just intrigued.

Comment: A problem per se? No. But a)it can make simple queries unwieldy, b)opens you up to possible SQL injection attacks if not done right, c)can lead to performance degredation if the query plan cannot be cached, d)dynamic SQL can't be joined with other queries, and e)takes away intellisense as you write the queries.

Comment: Well you seem to know a few things, so I'll take your word.

Comment: @user1676874 If you want to know more, take a look at http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html . It's long, but quite detailed.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use an unpivot - like so:

```
declare @month int
set @month=11
select monthval
from (select * from months) p
unpivot 
(monthval for monthnum in
 (month1,month2,month3,month4,month5,month6,month7,month8,month9,month10,month11,month12)) u
where monthnum= 'month'+cast(@month as varchar(2))
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fdb1/8).